# Электронная цифровая подпись

Tags: c#, шифрование

1. Генерация пары ключей асимметричного шифрования (открытый ключ –
   закрытый ключ) алгоритма RSA
2. Экспорт и импорт открытого и закрытого ключей шифрования RSA в
   файл
3. Хеширование текста методами MD5 и SHA-1
4. Подпись документа следующих форматов: *.doc, *docx, *.txt

Видел куски кода на c#, но не особо шарю в этом. Можете объяснить на пальцах, как это реализовать?

Comment: Берете готовую библиотеку и читаете документацию. Реализовывать это самому не нужно.

Comment: название библиотеки?

Comment: OpenSSL точно содержит все необходимое, например.

Comment: спасибо, уже читаю